# Two-step or two steps

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, numbers

Which sentence is correct?

> We process the data in two steps: First, .. Second, ...

OR

> We process the data in two-step: First, .. Second, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps means exactly what the the words imply:

> We process the data in two steps . . .

There are two steps involved in processing the data.

---

The hyphenated version doesn't mean *two steps* at all. A [*two-step*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-step) is the term for a particular type of dance:

> **1** : a ballroom dance in ²/₄ or ⁴/₄ time having a basic pattern of step-close-step
>   **2** : a piece of music for the two-step

So, it would be very unusual for it to not be a mistake if used here. If not a mistake, it would be a deliberate play on words by the author—a way of speaking figuratively about how each step interrelates with the other.

Likely, if it *were* meant to be taken that way, it would be written more explicitly:

> We process the data in **a** two-step **dance** . . .

---

Note that *two-step* can also be used adjectivally, rather than as a noun.

To demonstrate this, your sentence would need to be rephrased:

> The analysis of data is a two-step process.

Here, *two-step* has nothing to do with the dance, but is simply a different way of phrasing your first sentence: that there is a process that has two steps. The use of the hyphen is stylistic.

Answer (score 0):

You process the data in

> **two steps**

If you processed the data in

> **two step**

it might be a kind of dance, but you could have a **two-step** process.

[image]